# java.crypto KeyStore saves as empty file

Tags: java, cryptography

I created a KeyStore object, and stored a SecretKey inside of it. I then save the KeyStore to file. When I try to read the KeyStore, it's empty. Why is it empty?

```
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");
char[] password = "password".toCharArray();
keystore.load(null,password);

KeyGenerator keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
keygen.init(256);
SecretKey key = keygen.generateKey();

KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry ske = new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(key);
KeyStore.ProtectionParameter pp = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(password);

keystore.setEntry("superman", ske, pp);

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(Directory.KEY);
keystore.store(fos,password);
fos.close();
```

Comment: Are you loading keystore back from the same file? The code that you posted works, and adding a code that loads the file back i get a new keystore that contains the proper entry.

Comment: Yeah, I am. I also went to the keystore file itself and clicked on properties and it says it's zero bytes. When I load the KeyStore and try to access my key, I get this error: java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports this key: (null)

Comment: *Really* recheck the name of the file you save the keystore to (`Directory.KEY` in your code) and the name of the file you load from. The code provided in the question *works*, either your loading code does not work or you are not using the same file.